# Clumping factor test

Tags: microbiology

I'm come across this question and I'm somewhat confused:

In the test for staphylococci, the clumping factor detects:

- staphylothrombin
- DNase
- mannitol fermentation
- Fimbriae
- fibrinogen-binding protein

I know that bound coagulase can convert prothrombin into staphylothrombin and eventually fibrinogen into fibrin.

I'm thinking it's staphylothrombin, but when it says ''detects'' does it mean that the test concludes whether staphylothrombin is produced or does it mean that the clumping factor actually ''detects'' a substance?

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you have questions about policy please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).